# Webform 6.1.0 help text not showing

Tags: 8, webforms, debugging

I updated my webform Module from 5.3.0 to 6.1.0,

I have one the Following Error:
the help text isn't displaying its content on any form on my site (Example of help icon in the shared image)
[image: help icon]

It should return the following when i do the mouseover:
[image: wanted result]

I tried:

- searching on google: no clear solution
- changing the css and js file persmissions to 777
- looked into my console: no return when i do mouseover on the help icon ...

Someone have any idea what can it be?

Comment: When did the problem occur, when you updated Drupal or when you updated Webform?

Comment: the webform @PatrickKenny

Comment: @PatrickKenny I didn't touch the file composer.json before updating my webform module, where can i find the right configuration for the composer.json for the Webform 6.1.0 ?

Comment: @PatrickKenny **Resolved** thank you ! It works, i did the steps in the link you sent and it is working.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webform has several libraries that need to be installed via Composer.  [Follow the installation instructions in the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-frequently-asked-questions/how-to-use-composer-to-install-libraries) and make sure you have the libraries installed.